# Delphi FireMonkey app can not draw simple black rectangle

Tags: delphi, canvas, opacity, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

Just create simple FireMokey HD app, put TImage with align=alclient on the form and trying to draw simple black rect:

```
procedure TForm8.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  c: TCanvas;
begin
  Image.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create(ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
  c := Image.Bitmap.Canvas;
  c.BeginScene;
  try
    c.Clear(claWhite);
    c.Stroke.Color := claBlack;
    c.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.bkSolid;
    c.DrawRect(
      TRectF.Create(7,7,ClientWidth-7,ClientHeight-7),
      0,0,
      [],
      1
    );
  finally
    c.EndScene;
  end;
end;
```

And it doesn't work. Color of the rect is not black, it is kind of gray.  There some changes of the color in corners. Did i need to set some other properties or what is wrong here ?
I tried different opacity values (1,100,255,65535), picture doesn't change at all and there is no information in the help what the hell this option means.
Zoomed left-top corner:

[image]

Also tried to use polygons as it described in example. Same problem - rounded corners and gray color instead of black (Opacity property of image is 1, all properties as by default):

```
procedure TForm8.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  p1, p2, p3, p4, p5: TPointF;
  MyPolygon: TPolygon;
begin
  // sets the points that define the polygon
  p1.Create(100, 100);
  p2.Create(200, 100);
  p3.Create(200, 200);
  p4.Create(100, 200);
  p5.Create(100, 100);
  // creates the polygon
  SetLength(MyPolygon, 5);
  MyPolygon[0] := p1;
  MyPolygon[1] := p2;
  MyPolygon[2] := p3;
  MyPolygon[3] := p4;
  MyPolygon[4] := p5;
  Image.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
  // draws the polygon on the canvas
  Image.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawPolygon(MyPolygon, 50);
  Image.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  // updates the bitmap
//  Image.Bitmap.BitmapChanged;
 end;
```

Comment: Could you add a tag with Delphi version where did you encountered this problem, please ? Btw. have you tried to follow e.g. [`this example`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/FMXTCanvasDrawFunctions_(Delphi)) ? I don't know FMX, but isn't that `BeginScene` and `EndScene` important ? [self-destructive comment; please do not respond to it]

Comment: @TLama: Those examples from your link are outdated. Method BitmapChanged is not available anymore, it is under protected section now (and it is good news, because it was strange to use both EndScene and something else). BeginScene and EndScene doesn't help in this case. It is basic functionality and it is hard to find something in FM which is working as it should...

Comment: I don't know the reason of you saying that `BeginScene` and `EndScene` doesn't help, but at least you should call this function pair (and you're missing it in your code now). See the [`BeginScene`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/FMX.Types.TCanvas.BeginScene) reference. There is explicitly written, *Call BeginScene before drawing on the TCanvas.
To end the drawing session, call EndScene.*

Comment: @TLama: I am saying that it doesn't help because i tried it. I tried to play with different parameters and don't see any result. Just updated code example, now it has Begin-End scene, problem still here.

Comment: Try adding 0.5 to all the co-ordinates. I believe FMX draws on the pixel boundaries, and therefore draws two pixel wide grey lines, rather than single pixel wide black lines.

Comment: @Mike: It's sounds crazy but it helps :) It is almost what i need. But 4 pixels on the corners still not black (almost black, but not black).

Comment: @Mike Sutton: You should make your comment an answer.

Comment: I suggest using [`DrawRectSides()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Types.TCanvas.DrawRectSides) for your rectangle, since this method allows for custom handling of corners.

Answer (score 1):

http://roman.yankovsky.me/?p=1018

```
if Canvas.BeginScene then
try
  Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 1.5;
  Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.bkSolid;
  Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
  Canvas.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.bkSolid;

  for I := 1 to 9 do
  begin
    Canvas.DrawLine(PointF(50 + I * 25 - (Canvas.Stroke.Thickness / 2), 0),
      PointF(50 + I * 25 - (Canvas.Stroke.Thickness / 2), ClientHeight), 1);
  end;
finally
  Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to fix once you understand the better paradigm of Firemonkey. Firemonkey uses real coordinates, not integer coordinates. You unwittingly told it to draw lines that were centered the boundaries between pixels, so each of your lines were half in one set of pixels and half in another set of pixels.

Specifically, what happened is that your integer coordinates were interpreted as exact center points on a continuous number line. For example, say the point is 7. A line of width 1 centered on the point at 7.0 will extend from 6.5 to 7.5 on the number line. But because the pixels extend from 6.0 to 6.99 and from 7.0 to 7.99 on the number line, each pixel is half black and half white. Automatic antialiasing caused them to be drawn 50% black, which is where the two-pixel wide gray comes from.

When using FMX (now called FMX) you have to switch your thinking from integer coordinates to real coordinates, which is far more sophisticated and powerful.

The easiest solution is to move your integer-based math by 0.5 to the right and 0.5 down. Then a one-pixel wide line at 7.5 will extend from 7.0 to 7.999, which is what you were expecting. To do this, just add 0.5 to all your pixel coordinates, both horizontal and vertical, as you issue drawing commands.

The nice thing is, lines that are 0.8 pixels wide or 1.5 pixels wide will automatically appear thinner or thicker, respectively. Diagonal lines and other curves will appear correct without jagged edges. You can scale complex drawings and they will look perfect at any zoom level. (The math for the half-pixel shift stays the same for all zoom levels. The 0.5 is added after scaling immediately before drawing the line.)

The above is true for all devices: screens, bitmaps, and printers, etc. So the same code to draw on screen can be used to draw to everything else. When drawing text, you can use fractional point sizes for the fonts, so they scale with everything else.